# Bad constraint 1.2 grokcore.security>=1.6.1

Tags: plone, buildout

I'm running buildout, and getting this error:

```
Bad constraint 1.2 grokcore.security>=1.6.1
```

I am stumped trying to find where the `>=1.6.1` requirement comes from.  I looked in all the setup.py files of all the eggs that come before this error in the buildout -vvvv output, to no avail.
For background:  I'm trying to create a new buildout to replicate an existing site.  I can't use the original buildout, because I need to integrate it into an existing production install.  But the original buildout uses grokcore.security 1.2, and so far in the process I'm using the same version pins of all other distributions, so I don't know why this 1.6.1 is popping up, and worse, I can't find out where it's set.

Any ideas?

Here is the tail of the buildout -vvvv output:

```
Getting required 'five.grok'
  required by plone.directives.dexterity 1.0.2.
Picked: five.grok = 1.3.1
Getting required 'zope.app.content==3.4.0'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.app.content==3.4.0'.
Getting required 'plone.alterego'
  required by plone.dexterity 1.1.2.
Picked: plone.alterego = 1.0
Getting required 'plone.synchronize'
  required by plone.dexterity 1.1.2.
Picked: plone.synchronize = 1.0.1
Getting required 'rwproperty'
  required by plone.dexterity 1.1.2.
Picked: rwproperty = 1.0
Getting required 'z3c.relationfield>=0.4.2'
  required by plone.app.relationfield 1.2.0.
Picked: z3c.relationfield = 0.6.1
Getting required 'plone.app.intid'
  required by plone.app.relationfield 1.2.0.
Picked: plone.app.intid = 1.0.1
Getting required 'zope.password==3.5.1'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.password==3.5.1'.
Getting required 'zope.app.dependable==3.4.0'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.app.dependable==3.4.0'.
Getting required 'zope.app.debug==3.4.1'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.app.debug==3.4.1'.
Getting required 'zope.app.appsetup==3.11'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.app.appsetup==3.11'.
Getting required 'zope.app.basicskin==3.4.1'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.app.basicskin==3.4.1'.
Getting required 'zope.browserresource==3.9.0'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.browserresource==3.9.0'.
Getting required 'zope.app.interface==3.5.2'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.app.interface==3.5.2'.
Getting required 'zope.browserpage==3.12.2'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.browserpage==3.12.2'.
Getting required 'zope.hookable==3.4.1'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.hookable==3.4.1'.
Getting required 'zope.app.security==3.7.3'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.app.security==3.7.3'.
Getting required 'zope.app.authentication==3.6.1'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'zope.app.authentication==3.6.1'.
Getting required 'grokcore.viewlet==1.3'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'grokcore.viewlet==1.3'.
Getting required 'grokcore.view==1.12.2'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'grokcore.view==1.12.2'.
Getting required 'grokcore.site==1.1'
We have the distribution that satisfies 'grokcore.site==1.1'.
The constraint, 1.2, is not consistent with the requirement, 'grokcore.security>=1.6.1'.
While:
  Installing instance1.
Error: Bad constraint 1.2 grokcore.security>=1.6.1
```

Comment: What version pins, if any, do you use for `grokcore.security`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said it at the beginning:  I pinned it to 1.2, which is the "bad constraints" the error refers to.  However, on the site I'm trying to replicate it's also pinned to 1.2.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was missing a crucial version pin:

```
five.grok = 1.1.1
```

So instead it got `five.grok 1.3.1`, which specifies the requirement for `grokcore.security>=1.6.1` in `EGG-INFO/requires.txt`, which is not where I was looking for it.

This is one example where a better error message would make things a lot easier.